# Wubi installation creates equal size separate virtual disks for root and usr

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, wubi

I like wubi install better than a standard install in a dual boot configuration but I have some issues here, namely I was never able to resize the usr virtual disk so I be able to install more software without running out of space. Wubi automatically creates equal size virtual disks for root and usr.

Further more, it seems that no matter the size of the "partition" I allocate for wubi installation, it will always create 2 virtual disks of no more than 4 GB max for root and 4 Gb max for usr. I tried it on a 16 GB install, and then allocated more than 16 GB but wubi won't have more than 4GB for root and another 4 GB for usr virtual disk which seems to be the maximum limit for a wubi installation.

I use fat32 partition when installing ubuntu from windows but i don't think this is the reason I can't get a 6GB or more for the usr virtual disk. It would have been much better to have a single larger virtual disk for both root and usr, and a separate virtual disk for for home. Is there a workaround for this problem?

I know many people don't like wubi but I do, and I hope you'll keep it alive because it is truly a nice and unique piece of software and a good reason for average users like me to give ubuntu a chance, and use ubuntu without having to repartition hdd for a standard installation (tried it twice in the past and was unhappy because i could not shutdown windows as usual, had to actually press the button for complete power off).

Thanks for reading this, and I hope there is an answer for my question.

All the best to you all, ubuntu developers and fans!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FAT32 file systems have an upper limit on the file size. It's 4GB. That's why Wubi splits the install into separate 4GB `.disk` files. The maximum install is 12GB with separate `root.disk`, `usr.disk` and `home.disk`.

However, a 4GB limit on `/usr` is pretty much useless these days.

My advice - reformat the partition as `NTFS` and then install whatever size you want (up to 30GB). Or better, if you're already formatting a partition - use it for a normal dual boot and drop Wubi.